# Wireless connection keeps losing connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I'm having this annoying problem with my Ubuntu 12.04.1, upgraded from 10.04.
The thing is that my wireless connection keeps going out of connection every 15-20 minutes, and sometimes I have to reboot my laptop. I've started having this problem about 1 month ago, but back in my 10.04 I had the same problem.
If anyone has any idea it would be great. Also any info you need about the laptop, please tell me the commands I need to run to give it to you.
Thanks and hope you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it.

1. Click on the wireless icon at the top and hit edit connections.
2. Select the wireless tab at the top, select your network and then hit edit.
3. Go to the wireless security tab and input your password and save it there.

Seems cumbersome, but sometimes it works just resaving the network profile.

Comment: I've just tried it, in a few hours will tell you if it worked. For now looks fine, but I want to be sure.
Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Well my friend, you're awesome. That simple answer did the job. It only disconnected a few times because of my own connection.